# How to acces image url outside the domain for downloading perticular division in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angularjs

I have one code for downloading particular division using javascript. But my problem is in that div contain one image tag .my image src is a URL which is outside my domain.My download function is given below:

```
function download() {
    var options = {
    };
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [748, 600]);
    pdf.addHTML($("#invoice-POS"), 20, 20, options, function () {
        pdf.save("Receipt_" + $scope.ReceiptName + ".pdf");
        location.reload();
    });
}
```

My div is

```
<div id="invoice-POS">
   <center id="top">
      <div class="info">
        <img id="my-image" ng-src="{{Logo}}" alt="" 
             style="height:150px;width:150px"><br />
        <h2 style="color:black" >Invoice</h2>
        <img ng-src="{{QrImg}}" alt="" style="height:150px;width:150px" />
        <h5>Scan QR Code </h5>
      </div>
   </center>
</div>
```

in this div ng-src="{{Logo}} is an external url ,qrImg is genertaed from my domain  so qrimg is diplayed.Logo Image displayes in div ,but after downloading the div, Logo image is not showing,Qrimage is showing .Please help me..

Comment: Does the docs/api allow `src is a URL which is outside my domain`? Cross site scripting?

Comment: Logo Image displayes in div ,but after downloading the div, Logo image is not showing